# Dynamically importing flat-file data using SAS enterprise guide

Tags: sas, enterprise-guide

I am trying to figure out how to dynamically import data from flat files using SAS enterprise guide. Here are some of the aspects that I need to consider:
1) File names will have the format of foodata_YYYYMMDD.csv
2) Files will never be deleted from the Source directory
3) New files will appear daily, except if it is a public holiday
4) Files need to be imported only once.
5) Each new flatfile needs to be appended to a master sas dataset.

What is the best way to bulk import all files in this directory, that have not been added yet? I also need to keep track of which files have been imported already so that I will not import them again.

Comment: I'm not aware of a point-and-click method for doing this.  You certainly could write SAS code to do this (which would work in EG or in DM or Studio); there's quite a bit of code out there on data-driven importing files.

Comment: In general the problem you described can be decomposed into a series of sub-problems: 1.scan the directory and produce a list of flat files (i.e. list of dates) 2.scan the master dataset and produce a list of dates already processed 3.select the subset of dates (i.e. flat files) to be processed 4.process all these flat files in a macro do loop with an import & append procedure 5.insert some kind of check to ensure the process completed with no errors 6.schedule the entire process to execute with the desired frequency